# Shuffling the order of an array with Mongoid

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, mongoid

I'm using Mongoid's recursively_embeds_many to create a nested data tree (Rails 3.2.8, Mongo 2.2, Mongoid 3.0.14, and Ryan Bates' nested_form gem 0.3.1). Everything's gone swimmingly so far, but I've hit a snag and I can't seem to figure my way out of it, specifically, how to reorder the members of the array that get generated. I have a bit of JS to help me on the frontend manipulate the form, but I haven't been able to figure out to get that new order represented in the backend. Here's my main model:

```
class Navigator
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps

  embeds_many :menu_items
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :menu_items, :allow_destroy => true, :autosave => true

  field :name
  field :type
  field :position
  field :behavior
end
```

and here's the MenuItems model:

```
class MenuItem
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps
  recursively_embeds_many

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :child_menu_items, :allow_destroy => true, :autosave => true

  field :name
  field :url
end
```

Watching the server, I can see that what currently happens is that during an update, new items are added via the `$push_all` method and other items are updated via the $ positional operator matching for nested arrays method (which looks to be [Mongoid's implementation](https://github.com/mongoid/mongoid/issues/2545) of the [JIRA SERVER-851 workaround](http://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-831)). As a result, the position of each menu_item is always fixed based on where it was entered. I know that I could add any number of ordering attributes and strategies, but this seems unnecessary in Mongo since it is possible to have the order of the array be representative of the order imposed on it by a user.

I understand that Mongo has the above limitation, but it also seems reasonable to overwrite the array every time it's updated, in other words, use Mongo's `$set` operator to replace the existing contents of that array. However, I can't figure out how to do this with Mongoid. I was hoping that it might be as simple as switching my controller from

```
@tree.update_attributes(params[:tree])
```

to

```
@tree.set(params[:tree])
```

This results in the query being correctly formatted, but completely escaped. Then I thought maybe I could `$unset` the field first, and delete the hidden id field in the form, but that fails too.

It seems to me that this is a canonical use case for Mongo, but also that Mongoid is preventing me from updating the document in a Mongo-y way. I also know that Mongoid is capable of using the `$set` operator, because it gets used to overwrite the `updated_at` attribute that's added because of the use of Timestamps. If I could configure Mongoid to simply use the `$set` operator for an update instead of the $ positional operator workaround, I'd be set. Am I thinking about this the wrong way or missing something? My next step is to try to escape directly into the Mongo driver.

Thanks,
Carl

**UPDATE:**

```
@tree.update_attribute(:tree, params[:tree])
```

creates the correct moped output, but the data isn't getting updated. Even if I change something that has nothing to do with modifying the array.

**UPDATE:**

While I couldn't figure out a Mongoid solution, I was able to figure out a jQuery one: I was already using it to rename the array keys after using jQuery UI sort, so I added a couple of things along for the ride. I make a copy of all the items, set the existing ones to be deleted and then add the copies as though they're new. When the form gets submitted, all the old ones get deleted first then all the copies get added as new in the order they are on the page. It's not an ideal solution, but it works fine and I feel well within the spirit of all the technologies - the form is still being processed all at once and I don't need to add an external sorting attribute on any of the models. It won't work if JS is turned off, but then neither would the drag-and-drop sorting.

Comment: I'm confused.  Shouldn't navigator.menu_items be represented as an Array?  If so why not just treat it on display.  You could do something like navigator.menu_items.shuffle ? Just do it on display.

Comment: It is being represented as an array, but they also have mongo ids associated with them, so Mongoid uses an update process that targets each changed item. It's looking more and more as though I will have to do it on display and include some manner of ordering attribute. It just seems like an unnecessary step in Mongo - I was hoping to simply represent the order of the array by already having the array ordered that way, because I know Mongo is capable of doing so. I just can't seem to get Mongoid to do what I need it to.